# groupby function returns undesired result for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

so I have this dataframe here

```
>>> df
    uniprot_id protein_group protein_family protein_subfamily
0       Q8TAS1         Other            KIS               NaN
1       P35916            TK          VEGFR               NaN
2       Q96SB4          CMGC           SRPK               NaN
3       Q6P3W7         Other           SCY1               NaN
4       Q9UKI8         Other            TLK               NaN
..         ...           ...            ...               ...
561     Q96S53           TKL           LISK              TESK
562     Q13163           STE           STE7               NaN
563     P45985           STE           STE7               NaN
564     Q5VT25           AGC           DMPK               GEK
565     O00141           AGC            SGK               NaN
```

There are some duplicate values in the `uniprot_id` column
and I want to combine them and make idenitcal values merge but different values seperated by a semicolon because the rows for these duplicate `uniprot_id` values are similar but not identical

after applying the code below I don't get the result I am looking for, and I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong

```
df2 = df.groupby(['uniprot_id'])['protein_group','protein_family','protein_subfamily'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join(set(x))).reset_index()
>>> print(df2)
     uniprot_id                                                 0
0    A0A0B4J2F2  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
1        A4QPH2  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
2        B5MCJ9  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
3        O00141  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
4        O00238  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
..          ...                                               ...
547      Q9Y616  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
548      Q9Y6E0  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
549      Q9Y6M4  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
550      Q9Y6R4  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
551      Q9Y6S9  protein_subfamily; protein_family; protein_group
```

I need duplicate rows to combine and to look like this

```
    uniprot_id protein_group protein_family protein_subfamily
133       Q9UK32         Other            RSK; RSKb               RSKp90; RSKb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['uniprot_id'])[['protein_group','protein_family','protein_subfamily']]
         .agg(lambda x: '; '.join(set(x.dropna())))
         .reset_index())

print (df2)
  uniprot_id protein_group protein_family protein_subfamily
0     O00141           AGC            SGK                  
1     P35916            TK          VEGFR                  
2     P45985           STE           STE7                  
3     Q13163           STE           STE7                  
4     Q5VT25           AGC           DMPK               GEK
5     Q6P3W7         Other           SCY1                  
6     Q8TAS1         Other            KIS                  
7     Q96S53           TKL           LISK              TESK
8     Q96SB4          CMGC           SRPK                  
9     Q9UKI8         Other            TLK
```

If order is important dont use `set`s, because there is order not defined, use `dict.fromkeys` trick:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['uniprot_id'])[['protein_group','protein_family','protein_subfamily']]
         .agg(lambda x: '; '.join(dict.fromkeys(x.dropna()).keys()))
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: yes thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for. There are some combined values that are not in the exact order that I want, but thats just a problem with my original data/dataframe that i'll have to fix

Comment: @InanKhan - Can you check last solution?